# Basic Joint probability distribution calculation example?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

(X, Y) has the Joint probability distribution:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
 X / Y & 1 & 2 \\ \hline
 1& \frac{1}{4}& \frac{1}{3}  \\ \hline
 2&  \frac{1}{6}& a \\ \hline
\end{array}

So $P(X=1\mid Y=1)=\frac{3}{5}$ and $P(X=2\mid Y=2)=\frac{3}{7}$.

> My challenge is via calculation, how $\frac{3}{5}$ and $\frac{3}{7}$
>   was calculated in this example?

Comment: Does the comma mean $\vee$ or $\wedge$?

Comment: @barakmanos this is typo, fix it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$P(X=1\mid Y=1)=\frac{P(X=1\wedge Y=1)}{P(Y=1)}=\frac{\frac14}{\frac14+\frac16}=\frac35$$

---

$$a=1-\left(\frac14+\frac13+\frac16\right)=\frac14$$

$$P(X=2\mid Y=2)=\frac{P(X=2\wedge Y=2)}{P(Y=2)}=\frac{\frac13}{\frac13+a}=\frac{\frac13}{\frac13+\frac14}=\frac37$$

Comment: how you choose $a$?

Comment: @ElizabetNi: I did not choose $a$, I calculated it.

Comment: Sorry, I means where are you get this formula for $a$?

Comment: @ElizabetNi: Probabilities of all events must sum up to $1$.

Comment: Thanks I get it. very useful.

Answer (score 1):

$$
P(X=1|Y=1)=\frac{P(X=1, Y=1)}{P(Y=1)}= \frac{1/4}{1/6+1/4}
$$